# Cannot Install Shutter Elementary Os

Tags: software-installation, apt

```
pk@pk:~$ sudo apt-get install -f  shutter
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 shutter : Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgnome2-wnck-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-appindicator-perl but it is not installable
           Depends: libgtk2-imageview-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-trayicon-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libnet-oauth-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libproc-processtable-perl but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: perlmagick
           Depends: libjson-xs-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: That's not related to shutter. The problem is caused by something you did before... Maybe adding a PPA, removing a package...

Comment: @Maccer what might be the solution

Comment: Run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` then try to install shutter

Comment: @GAD3R after doing all these still same issue

Comment: Try this answer on U & L ; http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309806/153195